# How to add missing entities from Database First into Code First application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Have a application built in .NET with EF ( Database first) using database A.

Now I have another different application built in .NET with EF but code first and using same database A with some of its own tables created using code first in database A.

So right now, in 2nd application most of the entities are missing in its solution. now I need those entities in my 2nd project. But I don't want  them as part of new changes when I enter Add-migration from NPM package, because those tables/entities are already existing in database A.

Is there any way I can bypass those changes from migration script when I enter Add-migration ?

Comment: comment them out (temporarily)

Comment: @Jazb Those are many :)

Comment: You need a `DatabaseModelSnapshot` with the state of the database. Either generate a new database first model, or go back in time to when you did that via your source control system. Then create an initial migration and wipe the Up / Down steps.